# Memory allocation for C Datatypes

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
     unsigned color : 2;
};

void main()
{
     struct node n; 
     n.color = 1;
     printf("size is :%d\n", (int)sizeof(n));
}
```

How does the compiler allocate memory for this type of allocation?

The printf gives the output as size is :4

Comment: It does it by generating code that subtracts 4 from the stack pointer. Now ask a *real* question.

Comment: How is this not a 'real' question?

Comment: possibly duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129961/how-is-the-size-of-a-struct-with-bit-fields-determined-measured/14008523#14008523

Comment: @H2CO3: What stack pointer? A C implementation may place `n` in any bloody place it wants; It doesn't have to be "from the stack", and the `sizeof` operator surely doesn't care about "the stack". Please isolate your understanding of "the stack" from the C programming language.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Don't teach me C. And I'm not talking about the `sizeof` operator, nor do I confuse it with any implementation details (which OP was obviously curious about).

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm not interested in *teaching* anyone! I'd prefer you learn C independently, and correctly, but I'm happy to help debug your invalid beliefs if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler often allocate some empty space between two members of a structure to make the accessing the each member faster. This is called padding. The size of alignment is mostly dependent in processor architecture.

```
struct data_struct
{
    char a;
    int b;
};
```

If we get the size of the structure using sizeof operator on i386, it will come to 8. But the sizeof(char) is one and sizeof(int) is 4 so total of 5 bytes are required but the compiler allocated 8 bytes. Actually it allocated 4 bytes for the char member too.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler pads out the struct for alignment. This is not portable as it depends on the architecture of the machine.

Comment: This one isn't actually padding.  Bit fields always use the underlying type.

Comment: I challenge you to find even one C implementation that adds padding to this struct.  It may be permitted by the C standard, but it simply doesn't happen.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Does that exclude it from happening in the future?

Answer (score 0):

It allocates sufficient space to store the type specified in the bit-field declaration without considering the number of bits. In your case, unsigned integer size is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type other than a variably modified type.In addition, a member may be declared to consist of a specified number of bits (including a sign bit, if any). Such a member is called a **bit-field** its width is preceded by a colon
>
> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. **If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined.** The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.
>
> **Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared**. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

*——ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.7.2.1*

> When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char,unsigned
> char,or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.
> When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the
> total number of bytes in the array.103)**When applied to an operand
> that has structure or union type, the result is the total number of
> bytes in such an object, ncluding internal and trailing padding**

*——ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5.3.4.4*