# Why does this typedef give a sizeof() value larger than expected?

Tags: struct, sizeof, unions, bit-fields, xc16

I use typedefs of this form to simplify access to microprocessor registers and bit fields within them.

```
  typedef union
  {
     uint8_t        u8Byte;           ///< REG_8 as unsigned byte
     int8_t         i8Byte;           ///< REG_8 as signed byte
     struct
     {
        unsigned b0:1;                ///< Bit 0 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b1:1;                ///< Bit 1 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b2:1;                ///< Bit 2 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b3:1;                ///< Bit 3 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b4:1;                ///< Bit 4 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b5:1;                ///< Bit 5 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b6:1;                ///< Bit 6 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b7:1;                ///< Bit 7 of REG_8 type
     };
  } REG_8;
```

Unfortunately, `sizeof(REG_8)` returns 2 instead of the expected 1. Similar definitions for REG_16 and REG_32 return sizes of 2 and 4, as expected. `sizeof(uint8_t)` and `sizeof(int8_t)` return 1, as expected.

The type works as expected. For example,

```
REG_8  a;
a.u8Byte = 4;
```

gives `a.b2` a value of 1, so there is no alignment issue.

Removing the `struct` gives a `sizeof` value of 1, so it looks like there is a padding issue, but if so, why?

Can anyone explain this? I'm using the Microchip XC16 compiler (based on GCC) targeting a 16-bit processor.

Comment: My guess is that your 16 bit machine would have 1 byte of padding for your one byte union, due to strict data-alignment addressing. This is a guess, as I am not familiar with the machine/compiler.

Comment: @IanGabes On this 16-bit machine, words do indeed need to be aligned on even-numbered addresses, but the machine can access bytes at any address (i.e., no alignment requirement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably sizeof(unsigned)=2 on your machine, so any "unsigned" bit field occupies at least 2 bytes. Replacing unsigned by uint8_t should bring sizeof(REG_8) to 1.

See also this question:
[How is the size of a struct with Bit Fields determined/measured?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129961/how-is-the-size-of-a-struct-with-bit-fields-determined-measured)

Comment: sizeof(unsigned) is 2, but isn't the :1 qualifier is overriding this for the struct members? Furthermore, if the b7 member is getting 2 bytes, then shouldn't the union should grow to 3 bytes (2 + 7/8 rounded up)?

Comment: the struct members will each occupy 1 bit of an unsigned. (I don't understand the second part of your comment - how would you declare b7?)

Comment: If you declare unsigned b7:16, the struct needs two unsigneds, so should have size 4

Comment: Silliness on my part - I was assuming that the LSB of the unsigned b7 would represent its value. Please ignore!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that @twin had the correct idea, although I also found another solution. Two alternatives that give the expected `sizeof(REG_8) == 1` are:

```
  typedef union
  {
     uint8_t        u8Byte;           ///< REG_8 as unsigned byte
     int8_t         i8Byte;           ///< REG_8 as signed byte
     struct
     {
        unsigned b0:1;                ///< Bit 0 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b1:1;                ///< Bit 1 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b2:1;                ///< Bit 2 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b3:1;                ///< Bit 3 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b4:1;                ///< Bit 4 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b5:1;                ///< Bit 5 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b6:1;                ///< Bit 6 of REG_8 type
        unsigned b7:1;                ///< Bit 7 of REG_8 type
     } __attribute__((packed));
  } REG_8;
```

...or...

```
  typedef union
  {
     uint8_t        u8Byte;           ///< REG_8 as unsigned byte
     int8_t         i8Byte;           ///< REG_8 as signed byte
     struct
     {
        uint8_t b0:1;                ///< Bit 0 of REG_8 type
        uint8_t b1:1;                ///< Bit 1 of REG_8 type
        uint8_t b2:1;                ///< Bit 2 of REG_8 type
        uint8_t b3:1;                ///< Bit 3 of REG_8 type
        uint8_t b4:1;                ///< Bit 4 of REG_8 type
        uint8_t b5:1;                ///< Bit 5 of REG_8 type
        uint8_t b6:1;                ///< Bit 6 of REG_8 type
        uint8_t b7:1;                ///< Bit 7 of REG_8 type
     };
  } REG_8;
```